# In what order should I read Andre Norton's space novels?

Tags: suggested-order, andre-norton

I'm just finishing up rereading *The Zero Stone* and *Uncharted Stars* after forty years or so, and I've realized she wrote many more books in the same general setting -- I recall Zacathans, for instance, in another book I read about the same time I first read the Murdoc Jern books.  I remember one title: *Forerunner Foray*, but Norton's short bio mentions tens of books in the space setting.  What titles are those, and in what order should they be read?

Comment: https://www.fantasticfiction.com/n/andre-norton/

Comment: @Paulie_D - You should flesh that out into an answer.

Comment: @JohnP I honestly don't know Norton's wrok well enough to really expand on what joint universe the OP might be referring to. I just know that FF is a great resource site for authors / work "collections" etc.

Comment: @Paulie_D - Ah, ok. I didn't follow the link, I thought it was a straight link to a recommended reading list.

Answer (score 2):

A general timeline of Alice Mary North's huge list of work is here:

http://www.andre-norton-books.com/archive/Timeline.htm

This ties together a LOT of her work, but may help you eliminate reading choices from the confusion.

Comment: Wow, if I try to read all of that, I'll be searching (presuming these are not all available in print or on Kindle) and reading for the rest of my life!

Answer (score 1):

In looking around, I found two sites that give series and stand alone books in both publication and chronological order.

- [Order of Books](https://www.orderofbooks.com/authors/andre-norton/)
- [Books in Order](https://www.bookseriesinorder.com/andre-norton/)

Both of these list the publication order, and then if it is different, the chronological order. For the two you mention they are listed only with a publication order.

As I cannot find a source that lists any of the books in sequence other than series, I think they are basically standalone books and if you read them in publication order you are ok.